# Export all fields of functions in export function to generate xlsx

Tags: python, django

I have some functions in models.py class. Currently there are all fields mentioned in export class. I want to export all fields of function rather then mentioning every particular field which increases my line of code. Is there a way I could do it?
Below is the code sample of export function

```
def export_xlsx(self, request, queryset):
list_dict = []
idx = 0
for q in queryset:

    list_dict += [{}]
    list_dict[idx]['name'] = q.name
    list_dict[idx]['place'] = q.place
    list_dict[idx]['time'] = q.time
    list_dict[idx]['date'] = q.date
    list_dict[idx]['country'] = q.country
    list_dict[idx]['city'] = q.city

    idx += 1
h = [
    'name',
    'place',
    'time',
    'date',
    'country',
    'city']
gen_xlsx("export_file", h, list_dict, request)
return request
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django's querysets have a `value()` method that yields  `{fieldname:fieldvalue}` dicts instead of model instances, so assuming you don't expect to retrieve related models values, this should solve your problem:

```
for q in queryset.values():
    # your code here
```

if you need values from related objects then you'll have to pass all the desired fields names to `values`, using the `"relatedfield__fieldname"` syntax (the same used for related lookups) for related objects fields - ie if `country` is actually a foreign_key to a `Country` models with a `name` field and you want the country name in your result, you'll need:

```
fields = ["name", "place", "date", "time", "country__name", "city")
for q in queryset.values(*fields):
    # your code here
```

Also (unrelated but...) the way you add items to your list is uselessly complicated (and not really efficient). You could just build your dict and append it to the list:

```
# awful name FWIW... what about 'records' or 'rows' or,
# well, something meaningful ?
list_dict = []

for q in queryset:
    d = dict(name=q.name, place=q.place, time=q.time, #etc)
    list_dict.append(d)
```

which could be further improved into a list expression:

```
 list_dict = [
    dict(name=q.name, place=q.place, time=q.time, #etc)
    for q in qs
    ]
```

but since `queryset.values()` already yields dicts, all you really need is actually:

```
fields = ["name", "place", "date", "time", "country", "city")
list_dict = list(queryset.values(*fields))
```

Comment: @Ressaq that's another question, and there's not enough context to answer it. Please post it as new question, with examples of "validations" you may require. Also, explain if you're looking for a generic answer (code that should work with just any model) or a specific one (and in this case post the models code, the query etc).